# How to execute database function in FROM clause multiple times

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql

I am working on a postgreSQL database project, and I need to generate big data quite quickly.
So, I have a table called *pacient_info*, where pacient_id and corresponding doctor_id is.

Now, I need to generate approx. 1 mil. rows in table called *examinations*, where the first two columns should be the *pacient_id* and *doctor_id* and then some date, but that's not important.

Because I can't pick random *pacient_id* and random *doctor_id* (these two need to be correct according to table *pacient_info*) I created this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pacient_doctor()
    RETURNS TABLE (pac INT, doc INT)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT
        pacient_id,
        doctor_id
        FROM pacient_info tablesample system_rows(10) order by random() LIMIT 1;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

which returns one random tuple from table *pacient_info*. Then finally, when I wanted to insert to table *examinations* I did this:

```
insert into examinations (doctor_id, pacient_id, set_date)
select
    pd.pac,
    pd.doc,
    (SELECT set_date from dates where i != -1 order by random() LIMIT 1)
from
(SELECT * from pacient_doctor()) pd,
 generate_series(1, 1000000) as seq(i);
```

but that gave me the same tuple in many rows, since there is implicit CROSS JOIN between those tables. I don't have 1 mil. rows in *pacient_info*, but there are 4500 rows there, so there should only be (1 000 000 / 4 500) 222 duplicate tuples, but there are a lot more than that (500 to be precise).

Can anyone help me, how to make the function somehow execute each time for new row?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try changing `RETURN QUERY SELECT` to `RETURN QUERY SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`

Comment: that gives me "ERROR: column 'sql_no_cache' does not exist"
Are you sure that it is a valid postgreSQL command? I read that postgre doesn't have cache optimalisation.